# Does Anaconda search for packages in the global site packages folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, package

Does Anaconda search for packages in the global site-packages folder if it cannot find one in its respective environment site-packages?

Answer (score 1):

No.  Each installation in Anaconda is completely separate from each other, since they are considered virtual environments and are managed by anaconda itself (using [environment.yaml](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#creating-an-environment-from-an-environment-yml-file) files). Once activated the interpreter can only access it's own site-packages location.

For example if we did this:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.4
conda create -n myenv python=2.7
```

Most packages are not Python 2 and 3 compatible so if we were able to import a package (in Python 3) from Python 2 then you would most certainly get an error (and visa versa) since the interpreter could not understand the older language.

If it cannot find a package then you will get the usual `ImportError`.

If you want particular packages when creating an environment then you can use something like:

```
conda create -n myenv requests bs4
```

See [the documentation](https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html)